# $T^1M = \{(p,v) \in TM; \| v\| = 1 \}$ is a submanifold of $TM$ of dimension $2n-1$

Tags: geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $T^1M = \{(p,v) \in TM; \| v\| = 1 \}$ is a submanifold of $TM$ of dimension $2n-1$.

Comments: I'm trying to build the function 
$$f: TM \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R},   \  \  \  f(p,v) = \| v \|^2 $$

This way is correct or need to take charts of submanifolds? I'm having trouble proving that $1$ is a regular value.

Comment: \parallel is not the right symbol for this occasion. See my edit to the question.

Comment: Since the function is smooth, I think it is correct. Anyway, you can take charts, it's quite easy: $TM$ is a vector bundle over $M$  and thus it looks locally as $M\times \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $T^1M$ should look locally like $M\times S^{n-1}$, where $S^{n-1}$ is the sphere in $n$ dimensions and locally seems $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Finally, you can take charts in $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: is enough (why?) to prove that $1$ is a regular value of
$$N: v\longmapsto\|v\|^2 = \langle v,v\rangle.$$
Write it as a composition of functions, $N = B\circ\Delta$:
$$\Delta(v) = \pmatrix{v\cr v}$$
(the diagonal, linear) with
$$B\pmatrix{v\cr w} = \langle v,w\rangle $$
(scalar product, bilinear) and apply the chain rule.